# random margin between element in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, font-awesome

I try to show "stars" (for rating purpose) in my website.

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=fullstars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=halfstars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star-half-o"></span>
    <span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=emptystars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
    {{mark}}
</div>
```

For that, I show the number of full stars, half stars and empty stars.

The problem is that the result is not as expected :

[image]

There are unexpected margins between groups of "empty stars", "half stars" and "full stars"

Thank you

(Here is a code snippet with which you can play on)

```js
app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fullStars = 2;
  $scope.halfStars = 1;
  $scope.emptyStars = 2;
});
```

```html
<DOCTYPE!>
  
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <title> My App </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=fullStars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=halfStars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star-half-o"></span>
    <span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=emptyStars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
    
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use your web inspector and see if there are any margins or padding. You could also try putting the spans on one line

Comment: could you provide a plunker?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ywavgx a codepen

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive. (Code sample is on top of my mind at the moment).

```
ng-class="{fa fa-star : _.length=fullstars, 
                     fa fa-star-half-o : _.length=halfstars, 
                     fa fa-star-o : _.length=emptystars}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the spaces between the spans. Should look like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=fullStars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star"></span><span 
ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=halfStars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star-half-o"></span><span 
ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=emptyStars) && _) track by $index" class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
```

Having whitespace between elements actually has an effect when the elements are inline.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it by this css.

```
span{
  float:left;
}
```

[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgLZev)

Answer (score 0):

Spaces between inline elements is a common problem in CSS. There are some tricks to remove them, but they are not all very "clean".
Here is an article about the subject : https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

You can choose any trick you think is the best. But I would forget the "float" solution : floating objects are not a solution to everything... And I'd forget negative margins too, it's awful.

For me, the cleanest solution is the "size 0" one, though it has some inconvenient (see the article) : you put the font-size to zero on the container, and specify again the font-size you want on each element.

For example, in your case :

```
div {
    font-size: 0;
}
div > span {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

You'll probably need to wrap the mark in a span too.